# Length of an line segment extended from triangle inscribed in rectangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

[image: ow to]

I have solved the first two problems (1 and 2.1) but 2.2 is giving me trouble. I am able to find some lengths but just come up empty when trying to find the actual answer. If anyone could help me I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles $BAM,BHM$ are congruent, and triangles $MHP,MDP$ are congruent. Also triangles $BAM,MHP$ are similar.

Hence $HP/MH=AM/BA=1/3$, so $HP=2/3$. Hence $DP=2/3$. Also $BP=AH+HP=6\frac{2}{3}$.

Triangles $ABQ,DPQ$ are similar. So $\frac{AB}{BQ}=\frac{DP}{PQ}$ and hence $$\frac{6}{6\frac{2}{3}+PQ}=\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{PQ}$$ and hence $$PQ=\frac{5}{6}$$

Comment: How do you know that triangles $BAM$ and $MHP$ are similar?

Comment: @mathinjpm  You have already proved that $\Delta MHP\cong \Delta MDP$. Therefore, the $\measuredangle HMP=\measuredangle PMD=\alpha$. This means $\measuredangle AHM=180-2\alpha$. Now, You have to prove $\Delta BAM\cong \Delta BHM$. This leads to $\measuredangle AMB=\measuredangle HMB=90-\alpha$. Therefore, $\measuredangle ABM=\alpha$. Consider the triangle pair $\Delta BAM\cong \Delta MHP$. Following angles of these two triangles are equal; $\measuredangle AMB=\measuredangle HPM$ and $\measuredangle ABM=\measuredangle HMP$. That's why they are similar.